# Exclude certain directories in find results in AIX

Tags: shell, unix, find, ksh, aix

I am trying to search for all directories that have extended attributes (-ea) but that do not have a certain string in the path name. I am trying:

```
find / -ea -type d ! -name '*arcdst*'
```

however this still returns /arcdst and all directories under it. I have looked at similar answers on this site, but per the AIX man page -not is not available nor is -path. This is AIX 6.1 TL6.

Many thanks,
LarryD

Comment: Unfortunately I get the following error, but thank you for your comment `find: 0652-017 -print0 is not a valid option.`

Comment: @shellter Perhaps I'm missing someething, but I don't think the `xargs` is needed here... Just `find ... | grep -v ...`. Otherwise it tries searching through all the files' contents...

Comment: @twalberg:  correct. Late(ish) night comment in error. 8-/ Tnx.

Answer (score 0):

Your command is not looking for complete paths without arcdst but only are only for
directories with an other name than *arcdst*. 
I would expect find to find directories and files under the directory arcdst,
but find should skip the top directory in its result.

If you do not mind that a little overhead, you can filter the results.

```
find / -ea -type d | grep -v 'arcdst'
```

When you don't want find to look in the arcdst in the first place, than you can tell find not to look in the arcdst directory

```
find $(ls / | grep -v arcdst) -ea -type d
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `-name` you should use `! -path "pattern"` option:

```
find / -ea -type d ! -path "*arcdst*"
```

This will skip all the directories under `"*arcdst*"` path

OR else you can use `-regex` option:

```
find / -ea -type d ! -regex ".*arcdst.*"
```

Comment: This did work on my non-prod server, where /usr/bin/find is dated Sep 17 2012. But when I tried it on the prod server where my script ultimately has to run, the file is dated Aug 09 2011, I get this: `find: 0652-017 -path is not a valid option.` But even in the newer version of find the man page does not mention this option, I wish it did since it seems to work.

Comment: Hmm older find binaries might not support `-path` option. But `-path` is indeed the right way to get the correct output.